# ERROR al intentar enviar email con PHPMailer (SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.)

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Bien, implemente PHPMailer para el envio de emails en mi pagina web, esta bien implementado pero me salta el siguiente error

```
2021-08-31 01:00:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO bingopedia.ml
2021-08-31 01:00:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-08-31 01:00:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-08-31 01:00:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-08-31 01:00:36 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt534-5.7.14 qlSR_zEIS5q2b_-6VPBAl0gxRE2CYaeawtRucLGgxvx5DkRa5t3MrSt8L19xLF0ybOoJz534-5.7.14 6v9pFPPGPRpre8hzGqj7-uVVDQXmAH6nOXC2XzJ8_D2hxko4qMRoJZfL3UCKLC-R>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g8sm12089047qkm.25 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2021-08-31 01:00:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
No se puedo enviar: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

El código utilizado para el envió de email es el siguiente:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require "../src/Exception.php";
require "../src/PHPMailer.php";
require "../src/SMTP.php";


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "*******@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "*******";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    
    $mail->setFrom("******@hotmail.com.ar", "francisco");
    $mail->addAddress("******@hotmail.com.ar");

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Hola!";
    $mail->Body = "Correo de prueba";

    $mail->send();
    echo "El mensaje se envio";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "No se puedo enviar: ",$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Tape los datos personales por motivos de seguridad... Ya revise que la cuenta con la que quiero enviar el correo (*******@gmail.com) tenga activada el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras... Alguna idea de lo que puede ser ese error????

Comment: Hola revisa [Apps menos seguras y tu Cuenta de Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), por que si no lo has activado no te dejará enviar! Ya me ha pasado.

Comment: Te lo está diciendo claramente. Ese servicio espera que uses OAuth y, como tu script no lo va a hacer, te saca el error. Te dice claramente, autentícate en esa URL. La solución, como Miguel te indica, es que uses un application password para tu script PHP.

Comment: Revisando el codigo tambien se pueden observar detalles como que tu usuario no es el mismo que de donde estas enviando el correo, ya que estas iniciando sesion en un servidor gmail cuando lo intentas enviar desde un correo hotmail, puedes obtener mas informacion en [PHP Mailer GMail Setup](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L54)

Answer (score 0):

Desde el 30 de Mayo de 2022 la opción de permitir apps menos seguras ya no está disponible https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Como alternativa he conseguido que funcione con hotmail siguiendo este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371724/sending-mail-in-php-using-hotmail-smtp pero tuve que cambiar el host smtp.live.com por smtp.office365.com como indica en los ajustes de POP e IMAP https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/options/mail/accounts/popImap

Comment: David Vega, de acuerdo con tu comentario sobre las políticas de google, pero Hotmail para mi no ha sido la respuesta estan usando no tls, sino STARTTLS, que igual no lo maneja phpmailer, si encontraste como te agradecería la respuesta